# Pymongo include only the fields which are starting with a name

Tags: python, mongodb, pymongo

For example, if this is my record

```
{
"_id":"123", 
"name":"google", 
"ip_1":"10.0.0.1", 
"ip_2":"10.0.0.2", 
"ip_3":"10.0.1", 
"ip_4":"10.0.1",
"description":""}
```

I want to get only those fields starting with 'ip_'. Consider I have 500 fields & only 15 of them start with 'ip_'

Can we do something like this to get the output -
`db.collection.find({id:"123"}, {'ip*':1})`

Output  -

```
{
"ip_1":"10.0.0.1", 
"ip_2":"10.0.0.2", 
"ip_3":"10.0.1", 
"ip_4":"10.0.1"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following aggregate query, using PyMongo, returns documents with the *field names* starting with "ip_".

Note the various aggregation operators used: `$filter`, `$regexMatch`, `$objectToArray`, `$arrayToObject`. The aggregation pipeline the two stages `$project` and `$replaceWith`.

```
pipeline = [
  { 
     "$project": { 
         "ipFields": { 
             "$filter" : { 
                 "input": { "$objectToArray": "$$ROOT" },  
                 "cond": { "$regexMatch": { "input": "$$this.k" , "regex": "^ip" } } 
             } 
         } 
     }
  },
  { 
        "$replaceWith": { "$arrayToObject": "$ipFields" }
  }
]

pprint.pprint(list(collection.aggregate(pipeline)))
```

Answer (score 0):

I am unaware of a way to specify an expression that would decide which *hash keys* would be projected. MongoDB has [projection operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/projection/) but they deal with arrays and text search.

If you have a fixed possible set of ip fields, you can simply request all of them regardless of which fields are present in a particular document, e.g. project with

```
{ip_1: true, ip_2: true, ...}
```